# android: how can we done local storage in android?

Tags: android

I want to create a form in android in which it saves the details as user fills the fields so that if user left the application in between and when he reopens, the app resumes from where he had left with previously filled date if any.

I thought of using shared preferences concept but didn't know how to get there. I have seen many similar queries but I don't want to use this with button save . My form is with 5 Edit text fields and a next button.

Answer (score 0):

In the onPause() method, read values of views and save it to sharedpref. And in the onResume() method just read those values and set it to the views

Comment: Well, android takes care of it. If you assign id in xml to every element you want to retain the value of then you don't have to worry about it. If you're minimizing or pausing the app this will work. In case app gets killed/ crashes then you have to do it manually either in SharedPref or savedInstanceState.

Comment: I am using fragments so onResume() method will not  be called when i switch between the fragments since onResume() will be called only when activity's onResume() will be called.can you suggest any other solution to that?

Comment: Switching of fragments in your hand. Apply Read and write operation when fragments gets switched.